# Users with "Read" Permissions will not be able to see the yellow alert for pending pages

Tags: list, publishing-site, publishing-page, versioning

I have found this problem inside my enterprise wiki site collection. First of all inside my wiki library settings i defined the following version setting:-

[image]

Which means that any user with Read permission can see pending items, and I assumed that he should  also be able to see the pending warning message. But the problem i am facing is as follow:-

If a user edited the page and he save his changes, then the page status will be Pending, and a yellow alert will be displayed as follow:-

[image]

but if a user with Read permission access the same page , he will be able to see the pending content , but the yellow alert message will NOT be displayed , this how the page looks like:-

[image]

If i grant the Reader an Edit permission and he refresh the page , then the yellow message will be shown... so can anyone advice what might be preventing my alert from being displayed to Reader users?